# Redirecting without specifying file extension

Tags: iis-7

Experts,
I have been running my website on IIS from last 2 years on a shared hosting server where redirect was working without specifying the file extension.

Using following code I was able to redirect to test.vbhtml. Seems due to some changes on ISS provided by hosting company following doesn't work anymore.

Response.Redirect(url:="test")

On adding the extension to the file name, I see page gets loaded.
Response.Redirect(url:="test.vbhtml")

My question is:
What is config required in IIS so that it can resolve file extension name automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the writer of following article I could resolve the issue. Posting solution for others who may hit into the same issue.

[Article on rewrite](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/RedirectingASPNETLegacyURLsToExtensionlessWithTheIISRewriteModule.aspx)

```
 <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="removeextension" enabled="true">
                <match url=".*" negate="false" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{URL}" pattern="(.*)\.(.*)" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}.vbhtml" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
</rewrite>
```